# Не отображаются картинки в react-native

Tags: react-native

Использую 0.59  react-native,xocde-11, картинки не отображаются при релизе приложения на ios, а на симуляторе все картинки отображаются. Картинки находятся в папке  assets (не внутри папки ios).Адрес такой

```
style={styles.images}
source={require("../../../assets/1-2.jpg")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```js
source={require("./../../../assets/1-2.jpg")}
```

UPD: Тогда возможно этот ишью поможет Вам - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26699

Comment: Это то же самое же.

Comment: Не сработало увы

Comment: @CruelMan пробовал не сработало

Comment: @АртемСафонов какие у Вас стили в styles.images указаны ?

Comment: @CruelMan высота ширина и ресайзмод

Comment: @АртемСафонов высота и ширина статичные ?

Comment: @CruelMan да по 200